# Delphi save all values from different datasources with 1 save button

Tags: delphi

I got this form;

[image]

I want to save al of those edits with 1 save button.
But the problem is that those fields all have a different datasource.
Is there somebody who can help me out?

Comment: "Is there somebody who can help me out?" a rather poor question. http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#prune

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple go over all data sources involved and use `DataSource.DataSet.Post` (assuming the DataSets are already in `dsEdit`/`dsInsert` mode).

***Note:*** If your DBMS supports transactions, it would be wise to group all your posts in a single transaction, so that data/relations integrity will not be compromised e.g.:

```
MyConnObj.BeginTrans;
try
  DataSource1.DataSet.Post; 
  DataSource2.DataSet.Post;
  DataSource3.DataSet.Post;
  MyConnObj.CommitTrans;
except
  MyConnObj.RollbackTrans;
  raise;
end;
```